# How to retrieve Title of image url

Tags: html, xcode, swift, url

I'm collecting images for a UITableView where I use a custom url depending on the item code

```
var itemCode = prodCode
var strCode1 = Array(itemCode)[0]
var strCode2 = Array(itemCode)[1]
var strCode3 = Array(itemCode)[2]
urlStr = "https://www.company-site.co.uk/VirtualImageDirectory/ImageBin/\(strCode1)/\(strCode2)/\(strCode3)/\(itemCode)_Image310xMAX.jpg"
```

With the url I then retrieve the image with the code below

```
var image = UIImage(named: "Blank.png")
if let url = NSURL(string: urlStr) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
       image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
self.imageView.image = image
```

The images come in all shapes and sizes but when displayed in a browser using the custom url, each image has a title displaying the size of the image (i.e.: Image310xMAX.jpg 310x83 pixels). I need to get this title, how can I obtain it?

Comment: Do you want the title from the browser using javascript?

Comment: No this is for an Ios app using swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the dimensions of the image using sizeof to help me size the rest of the form

```
    let sizeOfImage = mainImage?.size
    let h = sizeOfImage?.height
    imgHeight = CGFloat(h!)
    let w = sizeOfImage?.width
    imgWidth = CGFloat(w!)
```